# Accessing the Recovery Menu on LCFW Pro-B10

Tags: psp, system-mods

I've looked a lot of places and I can't figure out how to open the Recovery Menu on my PSP 3000. It's got Pro-B10 LCFW installed on it and I've read the readme and while it mentioned the recovery menu in the changelog, it didn't actually say how to get to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it. To open the recovery menu on most LCFWs:

- Hold the R trigger while turning on your LCFW (useful for when you set your clock speed way too low)
- Run the launcher twice.
- Through the VSH Menu. There's usually an option that says start Recover (This one made me feel stupid >_>')